# Php nearby places script help

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, formula, haversine

I was reading http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html to get the SQL/Math. I wrote a little php script but i get no results.

```
    <?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root"; 
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "places";

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");

$lat = "37";
$lon = "-122";
$radius = "25";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('$lon') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '$radius' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20") or die("error");

$nearby_check = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
if ($nearby_check > 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $name = $row["name"];
        echo $name . '<br />';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'No Places found nearby';  
}
?>
```

Database structure and data is the same as in the Google code article.

Thats my Php script. Whats wrong with it? I am thinking it might be a SQL issue. Not really sure. This post is from Jan 2008, So maybe stuff changed?

Comment: It just isn't finding places nearby. Not sure whats up. I updated the post with a little more info.

Comment: Hmm, no idea. Have you tried expanding the radius? Set it to 2000 just to see whether anything comes up at all?

Comment: just changed it to 27 and it shows locations but everything is twice... Not sure why.

Comment: Then setting to 30 lists more but everything is twice... How do i fix that?

Comment: No idea. Do you have duplicate records in the database?

Comment: No duplicate records. :( Not sure how do fix that...

Comment: But i put the cords for Oregano's Wood-Fired Pizza and set the radius for 2 miles... Oregano's Wood-Fired Pizza isn't showing up... :( Change the lon by one finds it....

Comment: So -122.114647 to 122.114646 find its. distance <= '$radius' didn't seem to be a workaround...

Comment: Found a workaround. Cut off the last number $lat and $lon... If you want you can write a summarize of what we did and you can have have best answer.

Comment: You should not have $lat, $lon and $radius as strings in your query.

Comment: Why not? Later i'm gonna use Get or Post. I know about mysql real escape and things. So why would it be bad?

Comment: If the query returns duplicate records you can use SELECT DISTINCT... this will remove duplicates in the result recordset. Not sure if this is what you want though.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.geonames.org/export/

Use geonames.org to get what you want. that is finding near by places.

This server was never down. I have been checking this for a long time unlike http://webservicex.net.

You can use it in javascript as well as in PHP.

http://booking.com is using a servies like this to display hotels, airports, etc  near by a hotel.

I have been using this service for one of my projects.

geonames provides a database dump and they update this periodically i hope.

You can find more information in their site.

http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

http://forum.geonames.org/gforum/posts/list/499.page

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once('config.php'); 

$lat = "4.2709781";
$lng = "-120.2881378";
$radius = "10";

$req = $bdd ->prepare("SELECT id, name, lat, lng, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( lat) ) * cos( radians( lng) - radians('$lng') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians( lat) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markertable HAVING distance < '$radius' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 40");

$req->execute();

$datas = array();
$i=0;

while($tmpData = $req->fetch()) {
    $datas[$i]['id'] = utf8_encode($tmpData['id']);
    $datas[$i]['name'] = utf8_encode($tmpData['name']);
    $datas[$i]['lat'] = utf8_encode($tmpData['lat']);
    $datas[$i]['lng'] = utf8_encode($tmpData['lng']);
    $datas[$i]['distance'] = utf8_encode($tmpData['distance']);
    $i++;
}

$jsonOutPut = json_encode(array('markers'=>$datas));
echo $jsonOutPut;
$bdd = null;
```

?>